# Making Java Mail Body attachment as password protect

Tags: java, encryption, jakarta-mail

I have developed a java mail API program which will send the mail and it also attaches the PDF file , so finally a mail is delivered in which PDF file is attached.

i want to make that PDF file as password protected through my java program itself. for an example, when mail receiver receive a mail, receiver click on the PDF file. at that time pop up box need to be appear and user have to type previously generated password to see that PDF file. im developing the function but seems to be struct with the domain. please help me here.

```
 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource("D:/C_App/PDF/"+Employeeid+ ".docx");//add file path
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(Employeeid);//file name to be displayed
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);

            byte[] USER = "password 1234".getBytes();
            byte[] OWNER = "password 1234".getBytes();
            encryptPdf(DataSource source, DataSource source) throws IOException, DocumentException {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(source));
                    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
                    stamper.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
            Transport.send(message);
```

This code segment gives me syntax error too. any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add stack trace of the exception you are facing.

Comment: in the line of encryptedPdf() line segment it is Syntax error on tokens, Type expected instead. and in the stack trace its about Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
encryptPdf(DataSource source, DataSource source) throws IOException, DocumentException {
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(source));
                    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
                    stamper.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
```

1. This is a method declaration part, you are supposed to follow java
   method declaration conventions, like access scope, return type.
2. I can't see a call to encryptPdf() method in your code.

Comment: I also get struct with this part. that why asked help from anyone. truly speaking seems very difficult to implement this for me. help me if you can with the code segemnts